# Storing Multiple Matrices from a For Loop in Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, store

I am trying to convert the following Matlab code to Python:

```
  n = 10 ;
  T = cell(1, n) ;
  for k = 1 : n
    T{1,k} = 20*k + rand(10) ;
  end
```

It stored all the matrices generated from the *for* loop. How can I write a similar code in Python?

Comment: Can you please add an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a normal list:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
t = []
for k in range(n):
  t.append(20 * (k+1) + np.random.rand(n,n))
print(t)
```

Comment: I like that you kept the two-space indenting style of the question code :-)

Comment: This is correct, but an uncommon mix of `python` and `numpy`. Might be what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank @Mohammad. It works well. Now, how to see each of the Matrices separately in an array? For example, in Matlab, after running the Matlab code that I have mentioned in my question, I run the following `T1=T{1,1}` to see the 1st Matrix and `T2=T{1,2}` and so on. How can I do that in python? Thank you again.

Comment: I got it@Mohammad. I just need to do the following in python: `t1=t[1]` to see the first array, `t2=t[2]` to see the second array and so on.

Comment: Hi@ Mohammad. Can you help me with the following, please? I want to combine all the arrays listed in *t* into one big array  (10 by 100 matrix). In Matlab, I use the following command to combine all that matrices (arrays) in *T*: `T_all=[T{:}]`

Comment: @MMKarim be careful as indexing in python starts at 0, so the first element should be `t[0]` and not `t[1]`. If you want to have them all in one array you can use `tall =np.ravel(t).reshape(10,-1)`